# implementing Parcelable in a derived-graphic class for onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)

Tags: java, android, parcelable, onrestoreinstancestate, onsaveinstancestate

I want to save and restore some data for screen orientation changes (portrait/landscape).

For doing it, I implemented onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState in my class that holds the list that I want to restore. It seems to be working, and in MyObject class I implemented **Parcelable**.

The problem is that my object **extends GifImageButton** and implement **Parcelable** so I get this error in my object constructors: **"There is no default constructor available for pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageButton"**

```
public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass { // extends AppCompatActivity
    ArrayList<MyObject> list;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.episode_five);
    if(savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("key"))     {
            String[] colors = {"black", "red"};
            String[] numbers = {"one", "two"};

            list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
                list.add(new MyObject(numbers[i], colors[i]));
        }
        else {
            list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
        }
    }

    @Override
     protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", list);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
        list = inState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(inState);
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        list.add(new MyObject("three", "transparent"));
        list.add(new MyObject("for", "white"));
    }
}
```

**and for the problem, view the code below:**

I want to **extends GifImageButton** but then I get an error "There is no default constructor available for pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageButton" at:

**public MyObject(String number, String color)**
AND **public MyObject(Parcel in)**

Note: if I remove: "extends GifImageButton" and "public MyObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)" then the code is compiled.

```
class MyObject extends GifImageButton implements Parcelable {
    String color;
    String number;

    public MyObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
    }

    public MyObject(String number, String color) {
        this.color = color;
        this.number = number;
    }

    private MyObject(Parcel in) {
        color = in.readString();
        number = in.readString();
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return number + ": " + color;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(color);
        out.writeString(number);
    }

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new     Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }

        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Can I extend GifImageButton in my object class that implements Parcelable? if not then how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message appears because you need to call a constructor of the superclass in your constructor. If there is no explicit call, the compiler inserts a call to a constructor without arguments. However, all the super class constructors have some arguments, that's why the compilation fails.

In your case I wouldn't implement `Parcelable` in your class at all. The superclass doesn't implement it, so you'd need to somehow save the state of the superclass also, which will not be possible to do. The superclass is a `View`, so it retains a reference to the current activity, which can't be put into a `Parcel`.

What you should do instead is save not the instance itself, but the state you need. Your state is currently expressed by two strings. You can create a separate class `State` inside `MyObject`:

```
static class State implements Parcelable {
    private String color;
    private String number;

    //Parcelable implementation omitted
}
```

Then you implement `Parcelable` for it. `MyObject` will have a field `private State state` instead of the current two fields, a constructor which takes a `State`, and a method `State getState()`, which will return the state. When you need to save the state, you don't save the object, you get its state and save it instead. When you need to restore, you restore the `State` first, then use it with the constructor to create a new `MyObject` with the same state as before.

Comment: I tried it but then in MyDerivedClass I've errors. for example, in onCreate at the line: list = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key"); The error is: inferred type MyObject for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should implement 'android.os.Parcelable'. another error is in onSaveInstanceState at the line: outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", list); the error is: Wrong second argument type; Found 'MyObject', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<? extends android.os.Parcelable>'

Comment: @ErezShmiel Like I said, you need to save states, not the objects themselves. Of course, if you have a list of objects and try to save it, you'll not be able to because it doesn't implement `Parcelable`. You need to get the states from all the objects in the list, create a new `ArrayList`, and put it into the `Bundle` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you MyObject class has private constructor MyObject(Parcel in), make it public so compiler can access it